# Edit javascript code in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I know that editing Javascript code in Chrome Developer Tools is possible - but I have not found a similar option in Firefox. Is there any way to edit the Javascript on a page in Firefox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657229/how-can-i-edit-javascript-in-my-browser-like-i-can-use-firebug-to-edit-css-html Maybe here you will find your solution :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only modify your variables, inject more code, change DOM etc at runtime using console.

Firefox, by version 45, doesn't offer a way for the developers to modify the source files in the debugger and persist changes to the disk like Chrome does.